# How to check whether given Changelist is backout or not in child branch?

Tags: perforce, changelist, perforce-integrate, p4python, backout

Basically we have one CL ( e.g.1000000) that is integrated in one master branch as well as in all of its child branch . Now suppose that CL 1000000 is backout in master branch . Is there any way to check whether this changes are backed out in all of its child branch or not through script ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you backed it out.  If you used the "p4 undo" command and your admin has enabled the option to be able to re-merge undone changelists, you can just do:

```
p4 ichanges (source-branch)@=10000000 (child-branch)
```

If you backed it out via P4V or the "p4 edit" command, there isn't any queryable metadata that relates to the original change -- you could check to see if the backout change (whatever its number is) was integrated to the child branches, or you could take a line of code from the original change and use "p4 grep" to see if it's present in the child branches.